# Html tag <select> onclick event string to textbox input on same page

Tags: html, string, select, textbox, onclick

[View Image for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vbWw.png)

I have attempted to use java script to move the string from one place to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was not clear, but from what I understand is you wanted to put the selected value in your textbox

```js
$('#mySelect').on('change',function(){
  $("#myText").val($("#mySelect option:selected").text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="test">Test Value1 </option>
  <option value="test2">Test Value2 </option>
</select>  

<input id="myText" />
```